# https-options request fails (400 bad request) only in Safari 10 Mac and iOS cors

Tags: javascript, ios, macos, safari, cors

The **options request** is always getting failed(**400 bad request**) especially in HTTPS environment on **MAC OSX and iOS 10** in **SAFARI** **only**. Chrome and other browsers works fine (200). We tried almost everything that we know to solve it but nothing seems to work. Following is the ajax call with options headers with cross domain:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        headers: {
            Accept : "application/json",
            'Content-Type': "application/json"
        },
        type : "POST",
        url : userDataSource,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data : JSON.stringify(formData),
        dataType : 'json', 
        xhrFields :{
            withCredentials: true
        },
        crossDomain : true,
        success : function(data){........}}).....
```

We tried following modifications on javascript:

- Modifying the preflight headers ( Accept and content-type )
- Removing the headers.
- Changing the headers to small case and vice-versa.
- Adding some headers as per the response headers.

We made similar changes on Server side as well and made some Proxy level changes as well, but nothing helped. It is not a public web application but its inside organisation network.

Its really important for us to solve it as it is blocking the delivery.

Please help.

[image]

Comment: This one has a shouting title to get answer.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a server issue which is hard to figure out when having no information on the used server platform.
Have you tried to debug the code that throws the 400 Bad Request? There might also be more information in the log files.
When you're saying that it's only a problem in Safari and iOS it might be caused by the differing User-Agent in the request (just a guess).

Did you check if any other HTTP headers differ in the request in comparison to a working request (make sure to compare OPTIONS requests, not POST). You could try some variations of the request using Fiddler or Postman to narrow the issue down to a specific cause.

I'm sorry to have no definite answer maybe you could provide more information about the server.

Comment: Sorry to hear that :/. Does it also fail if you create an OPTIONS request in Fiddler/Postman with the same content (incl. headers) as the request by Safari?

Comment: We tried almost everything as mentioned by you but unfortunately nothing seems to work. Server is Apache as in the screenshot. Fiddler does not work well on MAC OSX and tried Postman not much help. We even tried to mimic the request and response headers as in CHROME, as chrome returns 200, but that also didn't help. Tried changing the user-agent in chrome as of safari. OPTIONS is getting failed - 400 in SAFARI ( iOS and OSX ) . Thanks